How to match 50 ohm impedance on 2 layer PCB?


I'm trying to make a 2-layer board with 50 Ω impedance from JLCPCB. The picture above is a 2-layer stack up provided by JLCPCB.
And the width calculated based on this is about 2.7 mm.
Other calculators also show similar results, so I think this result is correct.
However, I think 2.7 mm is too thick.
Is there no choice if I try to make a 50 Ω PCB with 2 layers?
However, the impedance calculator provided by JLCPCB shows 0.508 mm.
What criteria should I follow?


"2.7mm is too thick" Wide?

You could use coplanar waveguide instead of microstrip.

On FR4, you need a width of roughly 2*t for a 50 Ω microstrip trace over a dielectric thickness of t. This is consistent with the 2.7 mm figure for t=1.5 mm. 'Two times thickness' is a good figure to keep in mind for a quick sanity check without calculators.
The lower picture shows a calculation for coplanar line. It's not microstrip. Do you want to use microstrip or coplanar? It's not clear to me what the results mean. It seems to be showing you the track to ground gap without a defined track width. Perhaps the track width is defaulted somewhere else, or maybe is the same as the gap?
If a thinner 2 layer board is not an option (the microstrip track width will reduce roughly pro-rata with the dielectric thickness), then a 4 layer board is not much more expensive than a two layer board. This allows you to choose your L1-L2 dielectric thickness independently of, and much thinner than, the board overall thickness.

The RF width of the boards sold a lot on AliExpress looks quite thin
https://aliexpress.com/item/1005007205026373.html

@little_android Probably a 4 layer board. Not that any serious products were ever sold through Aliexpress...
